# Horizontal table menu with picture and text below

Tags: html, css, menu, rows, css-tables

Just started creating some basic web pages, and I wanted to ask: what is the 'correct' way to duplicate  3 columns (seen in the JsFiddle) into something like this:

[image: http://imgur.com/0lrvSBV]

What do you  use to make another  table row like that, and center the picture with the text?

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95L87/1/)

Code:

```
<div class="content4"> <img src="http://placehold.it/67x67">
  <div class="main">
    <ul class="infoBar">
      <li> <a href="#">god</a>
        <div class="infoBarText">foobarfoobarf oobarfoo barfooba <br>
          foobarfoobarf oobarfoo barfooba <br>
          foobarfoobarf <br>
          foobarfoobarf oobarfoo barfooba <br>
          foobarfoobarf oobarfoo barfooba <br>
          foobarfoobarf oobarfoo barfooba <br>
          foobarfoobarf oobarfoo </div>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">damn</a>
        <div class="infoBarText">foobarfoobarf oobarfoo barfooba <br>
          foobarfoobarf oobarfoo barfooba <br>
          foobarfoobarf oobarfoo barfooba <br>
          foobarfoobarf oobarfoo <br>
          foobarfoobarf oobarfoo barfooba <br>
          foobarfoobarf <br>
          foobarfoobarf oobarfoo barfooba </div>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">menus</a>
        <div class="infoBarText">foobarfoobarf oobarfoo barfooba <br>
          foobarfoobarf oobarfoo barfooba <br>
          foobarfoobarf oobarfoo barfooba <br>
          foobarfoobarf oobarfoo <br>
          foobarfoobarf oobarfoo barfooba <br>
          foobarfoobarf <br>
          foobarfoobarf oobarfoo barfooba </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Stylesheet:

```
.main {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1150px;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-size: 16;
}

.content4 {
    background: white;
    height: 580px;
}

.infoBar li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.infoBar a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-style: italic;
}

.infoBarText {
    margin-top: 25px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 14;
}
```

Comment: Kiran did you just neatly align my code? If so, Thank You :D I'm not sure how this works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a classical approach:

```
<div class="content4">
    <div class="main">
        <table class="infoBar">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/67x67">
                </td>
                <td><a href="#">god</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td> 
                    <span class="infoBarText">foobarfoobarf oobarfoo barfooba
                        <br>foobarfoobarf oobarfoo barfooba
                        <br>foobarfoobarf
                        <br>foobarfoobarf oobarfoo barfooba
                        <br>foobarfoobarf oobarfoo barfooba
                        <br>foobarfoobarf oobarfoo barfooba
                        <br>foobarfoobarf oobarfoo
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You, that does look it, however, how can I add 3 of these in one row and 3 in another one? I did something like this with the code before: http://jsfiddle.net/95L87/5/, but I do not know how to 'push' the image out to the left and add the second row

Comment: Used display:inline-table to get 3 in the row, but how do I break one row ? or do I have to use margin to simply push it out to the next line? http://jsfiddle.net/95L87/6/

Comment: You could enclose three of those in another `div` / `table` each, and make them `block` elements.

Answer (score 1):

why use a table? Use three divs and apply display:inline-block to it. You can also use bootstrap grid system to make it responsive

Kindly refer to this doc

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Or even better you can use the grid system to create two seperate rows with 3 columns in it. may b something like

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        3
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        4
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        5
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        6
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do I have to get a plugin or something to use the grid? Because if I paste this into a jsfiddle it's just 123456 below each other, changing the col settings do not do anything.

Comment: refer to the document first. You need to use bootstrap dependencies to run the snippet.

Comment: Sorry, I am looking for something a little bit more basic. Maybe without using any additional div's. I changed it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/95L87/5/ maybe there's some way to 'push' the picture out to the left? That would look exactly like the result I needed already